# How to add manually data to a function

Tags: jquery

I can't find a way to add data to a function which is sent to an AJAX call.

```
do_ajax_call(['firstname', 'firstvalue']);


function do_ajax_call(data) { 
     if (data == false) {
       var data = '';
     }

     $.ajax({
      url: "myurl",
      method: "POST",
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json'...
```

How can I add the `['firstname', 'firstvalue']` part so that it works?

Update, in the meanwhile i change the code to

```
do_ajax_call('[{"name":"value"}]');
```

if i do the ajax call i think the parameter wont send rigth. There i see [{"name":"value"}] and not a list like name: value

Comment: Your logic should work, but you're not sending a key with the data, so it depends on how you're reading the body ofthe request on the server side. I'd suggest wrapping your array in an object with a key which can be read explicitly on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be the best way to add data directly :

```
$.ajax({
     url: "myurl",
     method: "POST",
     data: {'firstname':'firstvalue'} //key with value
     dataType: 'json'...
});
```

but still if you want to do with the function

```
do_ajax_call({'firstname':'firstvalue'});

function do_ajax_call(data) { 
     console.log(data);       //{firstname: "firstvalue"}
     if (data == false) {
       var data = '';
     }

     $.ajax({
      url: "myurl",
      method: "POST",
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json'...
```

Comment: ok, but i have to use the do_ajax_call() funtion, how i can do it with this?